# Adding Library Source to current WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I am creating an app using the FirstFloorUI/ModernUI framework and the framework seems to be inbuilt to the current scope via the FirstFloor.ModernUI.dll (under packages/ModernUI.WPF.1.0.6).

Basically i wish to add more functions from the link https://mui.codeplex.com/discussions/446125 but from what it looks like i need access to the framework core files which are not accessible from the projects FirstFloor.ModernUI.dll.

I have copied over the Shared folder (taken from the github repo for firstfloor - https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/tree/master/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI/Shared) to the root folder of the project (to edit files/framework) but how do i add to the project and remove the .dll from the project?

Or do i compile the Shared folder to a .dll(How?) and copy over the original framework FirstFloor.ModernUI.dll?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Why don't you build the full project and modify it to your needs?

Comment: May have something to do with this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies.aspx

Comment: Kenny, basically i wish to edit the core framework code but it is contained with the .dll file. How do i access the content inside the .dll

Comment: Pretty sure the github repo contains the code that builds the DLL. That's why I'm suggesting you build the DLL from the Repo. Once you have it building modify it to your needs and build again.